# function for card game "Go Fish" that checks a player's hand for the guessed card from opponent

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to set up a function to check and see if their opponent has the card in their hand that they asked for.

I am trying to set the function up to return `True` if they function finds a pair and removes it and return `False` if it doesn't remove a pair.

That way, I can set up an if statement that determines what to do next based on what is returned by the function. Can anyone help me out with this?

```py
def check_guess(player_hand, player_hand_2, guess, player_pairs):
    '''
    This checks a player's hand for the guessed card and 
    if the guessed card is in the hand it removes the card from both
    player's hands
    '''
    num = 0
    card1 = guess
    size = len(player_hand)
    while num <= size:
        card2 = player_hand[num]
        if card1[:-1] == card2[:-1]:
            player_pairs.append(card1)
            player_pairs.append(card2)
            player_hand.remove(card2)
            player_hand_2.remove(card1)
            return True
        elif card1[:-1] != card2[:-1]:
            num += 1
    return False   #I added this at the end and when the guess is right it works but when the guess is wrong, I get an error message.
```

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11865956)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. On SO, ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341). Please ask a *specific* question instead. See [ask].

Comment: The "can someone help me" part is a just a general question added to the end. The actual question starts from the beginning, can someone help me figure out how to set this function to return True if the function removes a pair and return False if it doesn't remove a pair.

Comment: @Cameron That's not obvious from reading the question as it stands. Try reframing the question: "*How can I* set this function to return `True` if the function removes a pair and return `False` if it doesn't?" But then, this function *looks like* it'll already `return True` correctly, so what's stopping you from adding `return False`?

Comment: You may want to also consider the rules of "Go Fish"... if I ask for "nines" then you have to give me all the nines, not just the first one.

Comment: I am just not positive where to put the return False, because I tried just adding it after the elif statement, and that didn't work. So now I am here trying to see if I made a mistake that I am not noticing and hoping someone with more experience than me will lend a hand.

Comment: @Kurt Thats just a version of "Go Fish", this version only deals with pairs of two.

Comment: you would just put "return False" at the end of the function, after the while loop, so if the loop exhausts itself without finding anything the "default" action is to return False

Comment: Also, please make a [mre] including how you're using this function. I imagine `guess` is a string like `'9♣️'` and the other parameters are lists of similar strings, but it'd help to make that explicit.

Comment: what is the error message you get now?

Comment: @Kurt card2 = player_hand[num]

Comment: @Kurt IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: that is because a list of length 10 does not have an item at index 10

Comment: @Kurt I thought since I have num set to 0 at the beginning that when I wrote num += 1, I would get num to = 1, not 10.

Comment: yes and then every time the loop repeats it increments 0, 1, 2, 3... etc.  your loop termination condition is `num <= size`, so when num is finally equal to the size of the list, you get this error

Comment: @Kurt Ahh, I understand what is happening now. For example, if the list length is 10 it only has 9 items in it. So how could I set this part up to prevent this from happening?

Comment: no, the length is 10 because there are 10 items in it, but they are indexed 0-9 rather than 1-10

Comment: @Kurt Thank you for your help and I know I probably got on your nerves a little bit. I'm still new to python and this website, so I am still making noob mistakes on both of them.

Comment: @CameronBratten no worries mate, it's a very common error, we've all been there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem after making the "return False" addition is simply a loop indexing issue.  Your `num` variable is increasing from 0 to size, but a list only has indexes from 0 to size-1.  And that assumes the list is not empty.

Safer and easier to simply iterate over the list instead of using a while loop:

```
def check_guess(player_hand, player_hand_2, guess, player_pairs):
    '''
    This checks a player's hand for the guessed card and 
    if the guessed card is in the hand it removes the card from both
    player's hands
    '''
    for card in player_hand:
        if card[:-1] == guess[:-1]:
            player_pairs.extend([card, guess])
            player_hand.remove(card)
            player_hand_2.remove(guess)
            return True
    return False

my_hand = ['4h']
other_hand = ['4s','4c']
my_pairs = list()

check_guess(other_hand, my_hand, '4h', my_pairs)

print(my_pairs)
```